# Unable to connect mysql using ip address

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to connect my db using  host address  as my ip address 203.199.209.**,but not able to connect db.if i try  to connect my db using host address as localhost it connected successfully. 
How to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: are you allowing remote access

Comment: chumki... then how to connect remote system sql?

Comment: raheel shan..that only i am asking..how to allow remote access?

Comment: try to set in mysql.ini your ip address

Comment: Googling for "how do I allow remote access to mysql" turns up an entire page of tutorials.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL grants access based on which host you are connecting from.

Run this command as `root`:

```
SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;
```

These are the users which exist on your server. Notice the `host` column.

In short, a user is defined as both a user name (`user`) **and** a point of connection (`host`). When you access your server as `localhost`, you actually login as `some_user@localhost`. On the other hand, when you access the sever via its IP address, you actually login as `some_user@your.ip.address.here`. I guess the latter does not exist on your server.

You may want to create a new user such as `some_user@your.ip.address.here` or `some_user@%` (the percent sign is a wildcard; here, it means "any host"):

```
CREATE USER 'some_user'@'your.ip.address.here' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password';
GRANT ALL ON your_database.* to 'some_user'@'your.ip.address.here';
```

If you wish to dig further, see [this manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/connection-access.html) for more details about MySQL access control, and [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-user.html) for the `CREATE USER` syntax.

[edit]

Obviously, as suggested by others, you first need to make sure your server listens to this IP address (203.199.209.**). But if this were not already the case, you should get the following error:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '203.199.209.**' (111)

The error you are getting definitely indicates a permission issue.

Answer (score 1):

For mysql-5.7.15-winx64 (Windows Version), login as "root" user and run the following queries in MYSQL:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;

CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

and then Re-start your MYSQL DB.

For this version of MYSQL DB no changes are required in "my-default.ini" located in the same location as "bin" folder.